# How to set background for a sliverlist

Tags: flutter

I've develop an app.There is a page like this:

[image: screenshot]

If there are more comments, the picture and comment list can be scroll. So I put them in a CustomScrollView. The question is how can I set background for the SliverList?

Comment: The backgroud of the sliverlist is a png picture...

Comment: Can you show the code?

Comment: hi, do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this:

Add a grouping background by customizing the RenderSliver.: https://github.com/mrdaios/flutter_group_sliver

```
flutter_group_sliver: ^0.0.2
```

Comment: package is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Therefore answer is invalid

Answer (score 13):

You can wrap the 'CustomScrollView' on a Container, and set a color for that Container. This is how I solved:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            title: Text('Title'),
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(),
          ),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([]),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: i can't put `Container` on `CustomScrollView` because i already wrapped it with `SmartRefresher`which it's a flex widget. The smart refresher not working if i wrap `CustomScrollView` with `Container`. Do you know what to do to give the `SliverList` a backgroundColor ?

Answer (score 3):

Try wrap CustomScrollView within Container and give color to container widget.

Answer (score 2):

Any sliver in your `CustomScrollView` can be wrapped with a `DecoratedSliver`. This also allows your to give various slivers different background colors, while preserving the `CustomScrollView`'s property of dynamically building its children.

See also: [DecoratedSliver Flutter docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DecoratedSliver-class.html)

Screenshot:

[image: decorated sliver demo screenshot]

Code:

```dart
class SliverBackgroundDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliverBackgroundDemo({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Coloured slivers demo')),
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          DecoratedSliver(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            sliver: SliverList.builder(
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Child $index'),
            ),
          ),
          DecoratedSliver(
            decoration: const BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            sliver: SliverGrid.builder(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
              ),
              itemCount: 10,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text('Child $index'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```